# outputing custom csv header in reducer of map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

I am creating my own reducer as follows:

```
public class MyReducer implemts Reducer<K1,V1,K2,V2>{

 @override
 public void configure(JobConf conf){

 }

 @override
 public void close(JobConf conf){

 }

 public void reduce(parsms ){

 }

}


}
```

How can i output a custom csv header?I am not extending mapper and hence i cant overide setup method.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking on the OLD Hadoop API.

In the NEW API you can override setup method of Reducer, creating the headers.

Please see http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html.